# Getting an error when updating the image jpg

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error:

> "failed to convert parameter value from bitmap to byte[]." when i try to update the record, the image is not getting updated.

This is my code:

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Open();

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        pb1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("Update Stock_Jewelry  set Stock_Type = @Stock_Type, Stock_No = @Stock_No , Quantity = @Quantity, Item_Description = @Item_Description, Item_Type = @Item_Type, No_of_Gems = @No_of_Gems, Gem_Type = @Gem_Type, Image = @Image WHERE  ID = @ID",conn);

        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_ID.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Stock_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Stock_Type.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@stock_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_stock_no.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_qty.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Item_Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo_itemk_description.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Item_Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo_item_type.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@No_of_Gems", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_no_of_gems.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Gem_Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_gem_type.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pb1.Image;
        /*
          using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
          {
          pb1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
          command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray();
          }
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();*/

        MessageBox.Show("You've updated successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    conn.Close();

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Tell us a little bit about the environment/background? I.E First time, I've seen it done like this... I prefer to have a field "ImageFileName" or "Url".... upload to dir from app and use the above fields as a reference to that image on the server.

Comment: i am having two forms. one to stock entry and the other form which views the stocks in the grid-view. so now i am able to insert a record of data in to the database using the stock entry  form including the image is being save. now when i am going to update the same data. i will go to the gird-view and select and double click the cell then the form opens with all data and i could change all the fields except the image. i cant replace that with the existing image.

Comment: What is the actual column type in the table?

Comment: hope you meant in the database table. and for the image: datatype is image

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D5EpLZZ-2yVlOphaSBxOSC2vVLGabZ7W

Comment: my sql server database looks like the above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me...

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("Update Stock_Jewelry  set Stock_Type = @Stock_Type, Stock_No = @Stock_No , Quantity = @Quantity, Item_Description = @Item_Description, Item_Type = @Item_Type, No_of_Gems = @No_of_Gems, Gem_Type = @Gem_Type, Image = @Image WHERE  ID = @ID",conn);

        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_ID.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Stock_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Stock_Type.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@stock_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_stock_no.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_qty.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Item_Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo_itemk_description.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Item_Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo_item_type.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@No_of_Gems", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_no_of_gems.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Gem_Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_gem_type.Text;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
          pb1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
          command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray();
        }
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("You've updated successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    conn.Close();

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: its working found the error, its because  i have set the id to auto increment and its set as primary

Comment: i mean i have kept it as auto-increment and set it as id in the datebase table., therefore it didnt work. after i changed with your updated code. it didn't work yet. then i changed the WHERE ID=@ID to WHERE Stock_No = @Stock_No .. it worked perfect. why cant i do that with WHERE ID=@ID ..

Answer (score 0):

1. change field type in db to --> **varbinary(MAX)**
2. change this line : command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = pic;
3. when read from db use this method:

   `public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
           try
           {
               MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
               return Image.FromStream(ms);
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               return null;
           }
    }`

Comment: thank you for message sir, my image is saving after i changed Where Clause to stock_no. it didnt change because my ID is set to auto-increment and it is set as primary.

Comment: no problem when id is auto-increment... varbinary type is better for save image in db